# File not reading in selenium - maven framewaork

Tags: java, maven, selenium

I tried to create a quick framework. in that I created below-mentioned classes:

- Config file(All browsers path)
- configDataProvider java class(reads the above file)
- BrowserFactory class(has firefox browser object)
- configDataProviderTest class(access data from dconfigDataProvider class)

now its not reading the paths mentioned in config.properties file.

I have provided all correct path and attached screenshots:[image: Config file][image: configDataProvider][image: BrowserFactory][image: configDataProviderTest]

Comment: Post *text*. Images are hard or impossible to read and can't be searched.

Comment: @megha Is your question resolved?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a problem is at your `ConfigDataProvider` class.

***Firstly***, you using Maven for building your project. Maven has defined project structure for ***code sources*** and for ***resources***:

```
/src/main/java  
/src/main/resorces
```

Thus, much better to put your `.properties` file there.

***Second***, you don't need to set the full path to your config file.
Relative path will be just enough. Something like below:

```
public class PropertiesFileHandler {
    private static Logger log = Logger.getLogger(PropertiesFileHandler.class);

    public static final String CONFIG_PROPERTIES = "src/main/resources/config.properties";
    public static final String KEY = "browser.type";

    public static BrowserType readBrowserType() {
        BrowserType browserType = null;
        Properties properties = new Properties();

        try (InputStream inputStream = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(CONFIG_PROPERTIES))) {
            properties.load(inputStream);
            browserType = Enum.valueOf(BrowserType.class, properties.getProperty(KEY));
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            log.error("Properties file wasn't found - " + e);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            log.error("Problem with reading properties file - " + e);
        }
        return browserType;
    }
}
```

***Lastly***, if you are building framework you don't need to put everything under `src/main/test`. This path specifies tests with future possibilities to be executed with [maven default lifecycle](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html) - `mvn test`.

The core of your framework can look like:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Two things which I noticed:

1. Don't give path in your properties path within `""`
2. all the path seperators should be replaced with double backward slash `\\` or single forward slash `/`